# Is there a way to validate form in javascript to stop the onSubmit() java method firing?

Tags: java, javascript, html, submit, wicket

I don't know if my question is very clear, but basically, what I am doing is verifying the form in javascript code, in the same HTML document my page is. Then I call the method on the onsubmit like this:

```
<form wicket:id="editClientForm" id="edit-client-form" 
      onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)"  
      onsubmit="return editClientFormSubmitValidation()">
```

So I have a `<input type="submit" />` and everytime he is pressed the `onSubmit()` method in java is called. So is there a way to actually stop it from firing if the validation in javascript fails?

**editClientFormSubmitValidation()**

```
var submit = true;

if (addressNumberInput.value.length == 0) {

   showAddressNumberInputError();

   submit = false;
}

//A whole lot of verifications just like this one that will set submit to false.

return submit;
```

**Rendered Form**

```
<form id="edit-client-form" onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)" onsubmit="return editClientFormSubmitValidation()" method="post" action="./page?1-1.IFormSubmitListener-editClientForm">
```

**Rendered Submit**

`<input type="submit" id="save-client-button" name="saveClientButton">`

Comment: Why do you want that? write a function to do verification. On submit call that function. Add the end of the written function add the code for your action if everything goes well

Comment: @knightrider 

editClientFormSubmitValidation() is my verification function that returns false if things fail. I don't want to make it in the onSubmit() java code because that implies sending information to the server just to do verifications. I want it to be local.

Comment: There is no sign of any Java in the snippet you have posted. Is the JS `editClientFormSubmitValidation` function doing an AJAX call back to the server or something?

Comment: Please post the javascript code, specifically the editClientFormSubmitValidation() function.

Comment: Is this snippet from the template or the generated page? Wouldn't Wicket simply overwrite your `onsubmit` attribute when it generates the output?

Comment: This snippet is my javascript function in my html file. @bobince take a look at the function.

Comment: @PoniesAreDevilishCreatures And what does the rendered tag look like?

Comment: @biziclop Sorry, what rendered tag?

Comment: The `form` tag. Could you also show the rendered tag of the submit button?

Comment: The output HTML that you see in the browser.

Comment: @ChristophLeiter There you go.

Comment: @biziclop added rendered tag.

Answer (score 2):

return false from the editClientFormSubmitValidation() function, when the validation fails. It should work

Comment: I'm doing this and it is still being called =/

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you have a JavaScript error inside `editClientFormSubmitValidation`. If a JS event handler fails then the event in question will carry on to its default action as normal - for a `form.onsubmit` handler that means that the form will be submitted if the validation function has an error.

We can't see what the error is without more code (though I have a suspicion you might be missing an assignment/declaration for the `addressNumberInput` variable?), so open your browser's JavaScript console and look for errors there.

Comment: The problem is not in editClientFormSubmitValidation. I put some alert dialogs in every comparison and checked the submit variable in the end on the method and it is returning false. Also, I use those inputs in other methods, and those methods work, so it's not an assignment/declaration issue either. Anyway, I decided to put the verification in java, server side, as simply disabling javascript would ruin the verification.

Comment: Eek! Yes, you certainly need server-side validation in all cases. Client-side validation is for convenience only.